# Redirect www to non-www with site installed in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

EDIT: Turned out to be a DNS configuration issue. I couldn't see it because it was configured incorrectly on the host's end, and wasn't showing up as broken on my end. For anyone having the same sort of problem, try to ping your website - if the ping goes through to one and not the other (www or non-www) use MxTools or something to check your DNS config.

I have a Joomla website at site.com.au installed in public_html/subfolder

The redirect works properly to remove the /subfolder from the url, but I CANNOT get it to work with www redirecting to non-www. Going to site.com.au works, going www.site.com.au times out. I've called the web host (Crazy Domains) and the guy spent 20 minutes trying to figure it out and couldn't.

Current htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subfolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subfolder/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have also tried

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} subfolder/
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*) http://site.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a DNS configuration issue. I couldn't see it because it was configured incorrectly on the host's end, and wasn't showing up as broken on my end. For anyone having the same sort of problem, try to ping your website - if the ping goes through to one and not the other (www or non-www) use MxTools or something to check your DNS config.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Should help

Comment: Nope that didn't work. My htaccess is now

'RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdir/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com\.au$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]'